# Несколько вопросов ajax

Tags: ajax, php

1. Вообщем, при добавлении сообщения, все сообщения загружаются заново, а не только последнее, как можно исправить это ?
2. Как можно сделать скроллинг сообщений, внутри блока, пытался найти подобное в гугле, но постоянно попадается, догрузка контента по типу пагинации, как можно реализовать обычный скроллинг ?

Сам скрипт, который на данный момент уже есть http://dumpz.org/1168279/ буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: На то, когда мешают html и js, я лично еще смотрю сквозь пальцы, но когда смешивают php и js - просто не догоняю. Откуда и что там у вас за переменные берутся, можно только догадываться.

 1. Для того, чтоб подгружалось только последнее сообщение, надо передавать в запросе, как минимум, id этого или последнего известного сообщения и в обработчике делать SQL-запрос с этим условием.
 2. Свойство для блока: **overflow: scroll или auto;** или **overflow-y: scroll или auto;**, при этом, элемент должен иметь фиксированную высоту. Это, если я правильно понял то, что вы имели в виду под "скроллингом"

Comment: @Deonis переменные содержат айди юзера, и айди диалога.

Comment: @rnddev, замечтательно. Теперь добавьте в передаваемые данные то, что я писал выше. Есть, к примеру, у вас на экране три сообщения, возьмите id последнего и подгружайте те, у которых в БД id > это

Comment: @Deonis так все дело в том, что тут несколько нюансов, к примеру при первом входе в диалог грузятся все месаги, но хотелось бы чтобы грузились несколько последних, и при прокрутки вверх подгружались более старые

Comment: @rnddev, при первой загрузке ставьте лимит. Или что-то мешает? У вас эта первая загрузка происходит вместе с загрузкой страницы? Хотя, какая разница. Даже если нет, то можно же проверить - есть вообще сообщения или нет. Нету? Значит выводим последние десять.

Comment: @Deonis а догрузка старых, при скроллинге вверх ?

Comment: @rnddev, а что вас смущает? Передавайте вместе с сообщениями и id записи, на которой остановились. Потом, при очередном запросе, передаёте этот id и выбираете записи, уже отталкиваясь от него.

P.S. В конце концов, найдите какой-нибудь плагин "постраничной навигации" на Ajax/jQuery. По сути, вам примерно нужно в этом роде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не смотрел на код, но проблемы очевидны, сталкивался при создании чатика.

1) Расскажу смысл некоторых структур подобных аналогов, которые я в свое время находил, плохо с объяснениями, но как нибудь разберите и уловите смысл))) - в JS создаем глобальную переменную $now_id; В процедуру updateShoutbox мы будем подавать 2 параметра в data, $now_id и $dg['id']. updateShoutbox в свою очередь принимает эти 2 параметра ($dg['id'] - я так понял это переменка служит для запроса чтобы мы могли получить сообщения, но в базе сообщений она не является ключом, ключ у вас другой, запомним его как $msg_key при ответе). Когда мы получили текущее сообщение (последнее например) мы проверяем с $now_id, если равно, то значит это последнее сообщение, возвращаем 0, если появилось новое, то скрипт прорабатывает и возвращает вам массив из 2ух переменных: $msg_key и $msg_text. Теперь дело за малым $now_id = $msg_key; а текст кидаем в фильтры (смайликов и т.д.) потом полученный результат ДОПИСЫВАЕМ в окно с ответами. Профит!

2)

```
.prokrutka {
height: 100px; /* высота нашего блока */
width: 100px; /* ширина нашего блока */
overflow-x: scroll; /* прокрутка по горизонтали */
overflow-y: scroll; /* прокрутка по вертикали */
}
```